# How to retrieve the metadata associated with the highest numbered JSON timestamp?

Tags: php, json, bash

I am trying to parse metadata in JSON format for an external application. However, I only need the last played song's metadata and the JSON I have to deal with has 10 or 15 songs.

wklh.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -v --silent http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory >/var/tmp/wklh$1.a.txt
pta=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.a.txt | grep songs > /var/tmp/wklh$1.b.txt`
ptb=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.b.txt | sed -n -e '/var songs = /,/; <span title/ p' > /var/tmp/wklh$1.c.txt`
ptc=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.c.txt | grep songs > /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
ptd=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt | sed -i 's/var songs = \[//g' /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
ptd=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt | sed -i 's/<ol class="songs tracks"><\/ol>//g' /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
ptd=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt | sed -i 's/\]//g' /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
ptd=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt | sed -i 's/;//g' /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`

json=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
echo $json

metadata=`php /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php $json`
echo $metadata
```

I realize this is not efficient, but some of the sed statements didn't work altogether so I had to separate them.

wklh.sh:

```
<?php
$md=json_decode($argv[1]);
$title=$md->title;
$artist=$md->artist;
$album=$md->album;
echo "$title*$artist*$album";
?>
```

This is almost the same as another PHP file, writ.php, I use to parse similar JSON (https://us.api.iheart.com/api/v3/live-meta/stream/2689/currentTrackMeta)

writ.php parses:

```
{"artistId":893,"albumId":58817688,"trackId":58817690,"title":"Cum on Feel the Noize","artist":"Quiet Riot","album":"Metal Health","trackDuration":287,"imagePath":"http://image.iheart.com/ihr-ingestion-pipeline-production-sbmg/A10301A0001103372T_20180629201531958/4476232.20126.jpg","explicitLyrics":false,"lyricsId":0,"startTime":1555263475000,"endTime":1555263681000,"playbackRights":{"onDemand":true},"dataSource":"Pnp"}
```

Here is writ.php:

```
<?php
$url = "https://us.api.iheart.com/api/v3/live-meta/stream/2689/currentTrackMeta";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$md = json_decode($contents);
$title = $md->title;
$artist = $md->artist;
$album = $md->album;
echo "$title*$artist*$album";
?>
```

wklh.sh sends the following to wklh.php:

```
{"timestamp":1555254209000,"title":"Back On The Chain Gang","trackId":"5f_6e4abbe7-c71b-48c0-8412-7b471e514164","artist":"The Pretenders","artistId":"a0_e9c832b0-384b-4ee6-aec0-111372784aac","album":"The Singles","albumId":"9f_ca6cda27-1fe7-4264-9ba7-acbc6ccf658b","npe_id":"9242bddc7ab5d1560103303a30f581072a"},{"timestamp":1555254438000,"title":"Blowin' Free","trackId":"a5_fefb9583-8401-442e-8fe1-743f259ca8a2","artist":"Wishbone Ash","artistId":"8e_406f1b42-0c9e-4427-aeb7-02f78e188ec4","album":"Argus","albumId":"b9_40b81523-e997-489e-b007-b91381eadf2a","npe_id":"899578f2074ccbe100241441e85adf04e1"},{"timestamp":1555255800000,"title":"Eighteen","trackId":"5c_e7a1326d-be32-4f64-8feb-e8292277724c","artist":"Alice Cooper","artistId":"a5_ee58c59f-8e7f-4430-b8ca-236c4d3745ae","album":"School's Out and Other Hits","albumId":"34_5a7df40f-0d84-40e6-84b1-71c6cef5224d","npe_id":"e3fcf5b90e463320383bbf84050653c63e"},{"timestamp":1555260315000,"title":"Breakfast in America","trackId":"5b_da4b050d-a32a-4159-aee9-77e1fc7f3e13","artist":"Supertramp","artistId":"bf_d2ff6b6b-fc30-48dc-8952-06f9d8fc64f8","album":"Breakfast In America","albumId":"47_d779ab27-4095-4ad9-9663-d4ffd567aa4e","npe_id":"eee7f84d2b6879bc782151c3a516afd916"},{"timestamp":1555261272000,"title":"Spirit of Radio","trackId":"3c_63802349-97dd-4967-9bba-2ea2213262cb","artist":"Rush","artistId":"e5_eb62559f-2fb2-4879-af18-a23ea2ee91b1","album":"The Best Symfo Rock","albumId":"ba_5f3d58e6-e3ca-410b-80ea-317f4cd1afe9","npe_id":"4fd76d35647d3eb645be92b3679b77d64d"},{"timestamp":1555261568000,"title":"Beast of Burden","trackId":"09_55956d3e-c5d4-4332-a377-bf77c463656e","artist":"The Rolling Stones","artistId":"1b_b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f598","album":"Some Girls","albumId":"95_635239b4-986a-4cb7-90ba-bf213d5c9f78","npe_id":"f0b17c7012050705702a2e93fd1976288c"},{"timestamp":1555261829000,"title":"For Those About to Rock (We Salute You)","trackId":"d1_3ee8a730-413d-4f8e-b1c0-bd2694a65aa4","artist":"AC\/DC","artistId":"b6_66c662b6-6e2f-4930-8610-912e24c63ed1","album":"Who Made Who","albumId":"af_8de9dab6-6ff5-4a3e-b191-00ec7e974ef8","npe_id":"55c6ddd902781b70d28dc724cda5e9f325"},{"timestamp":1555262568000,"title":"Foreplay \/ Long Time","trackId":"21_b841b5f6-b968-4e83-8991-f1665ae96784","artist":"Boston","artistId":"f8_0d8b0d50-e4cf-4da4-965d-f24c58ec3268","album":"Boston","albumId":"b3_5c70a6a9-43ab-448d-a53e-0c7e933a6856","npe_id":"694f76ee4d7c2474b36b6984be7ee8e590"},{"timestamp":1555263036000,"title":"Scar Tissue","trackId":"de_3ec5cb52-7dde-4d11-aec2-1c1af8fc559c","artist":"Red Hot Chili Peppers","artistId":"c8_8bfac288-ccc5-448d-9573-c33ea2aa5c30","album":"Greatest Hits","albumId":"fc_b95d3a86-6640-4a02-850a-2b842ad601d3","npe_id":"815bf692959cd3f61f3f274e5e2085841c"},{"timestamp":1555263252000,"title":"Take It Easy","trackId":"d7_d5abb4ca-8cd5-468a-bdbc-53f3223bb9be","artist":"Eagles","artistId":"5e_f46bd570-5768-462e-b84c-c7c993bbf47e","album":"The Very Best of the Eagles","albumId":"34_9c6af437-a471-4bcd-9442-e5b9d9b9d064","npe_id":"58658057287a5ed71751f1983a8b00387d"}
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php on line 4
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php on line 5
```

The JSON that wklh.php receives is similar to that received by writ.php, only that one returns metadata for 1 song whereas my script returns the metadata for the last 10 or 15 songs. I am only interested in the same three fields for the most recently played song. How would I parse the JSON for the last (highest numbered) timestamp, then returned only the contents between the braces (including the braces) for that song?

My wklh.sh/writ.php script combo should work just fine after I figure out I can use PHP to select the subset of the JSON that I need. After that, the PHP code is similar to the one I use for writ.php and I can just use that. Is there a modification I can make to my PHP script to accomplish this?

Thanks!

** UPDATE **

Code returned when using the script in the answer:

```
{ "timestamp": 1555267001000, "title": "Foolin'", "trackId": "f6_a3e1ef19-9120-410c-b1fe-1a2609145e52", "artist": "Def Leppard", "artistId": "c1_7249b899-8db8-43e7-9e6e-22f1e736024e", "album": "Pyromania", "albumId": "5a_77797bc1-738f-357c-8c5a-233042906849", "npe_id": "0dfb9d624a4f118d2ffe9ec621c5fdc9cc" }
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php on line 4
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php on line 5
```

Here is the php I am using again:

```
<?php
$md=json_decode($argv[1]);
$title=$md->title;
$artist=$md->artist;
$album=$md->album;
echo "$title*$artist*$album";
?>
```

If I run the php script directly:

```
/etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$argv[1]'
/etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php: line 2: `$md=json_decode($argv[1]);'
```

Comment: @Amessihel Thanks, the only thing with your approach is there is a [ at the beginning and a ]; at the end

Comment: @Amessihel Actually, you gave me another idea - is it possible to simply return, of everything still present, the very last {} (the last song only)? Not sure how to do this with grep/sed though, I've only done return the first, not last, before

Comment: You can edit the regexp to keep only what you want. But you can certainly perform what you want in one sed line. For your last question, I'll write an answer (you should edit your question to get it fitting with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked a single command in your last comment, here, in one line (maybe improvable) way to get the very last song in bash (requires jq):

```
curl -v --silent http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory |
sed -nr 's/^.*\s*var songs\s*=\s*(\[[^]]+\]).*$/\1/p' |
jq -r '.[length-1]'
```

However, this code assumes everything goes as expected (the HTML output doesn't change, is retrieved, a valid JSON is in it, etc.

Comment: My only issue now is I assumed wrong before - my PHP script is still having trouble parsing this. I've updated the question

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to make it fit to this answer (in a Jeopardy way) by only letting what's related to JSON retrieving, and ask another question for the PHP parsing issue. Otherwise this question may be too broad to be given help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the json assigned to `var songs` is a single line.

If so, then it can be extracted by:

```
curl -v --silent http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory |\
sed '
    / var songs = /!d;  # ignore anything except the assignment
    s/^[^[]*//;         # strip prefix
    s/[^]]*$//;         # strip suffix
    q;                  # quit as nothing else should match
'
```

This can then be piped into jq for further processing.

If we assume no nested `{}` we can extract the final element directly:

```
curl -v --silent http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory |\
sed '
    / var songs = /!d;
    s/^.*{/{/;
    s/}.*$/}/;
    q;
'
```

Answer (score 1):

@Amessihel's answer is cool, but here is an answer that doesn't use `php` or `jq`. It seems like your goal is to print *title***artist***album* for the most recently played song. As luck would have it, the most recently played song appears last in the list, so we just need to extract the last element of the json array.

```
curl -s http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory |
  grep -o '\[{"timestamp":.*\]' |
  sed 's/},{/\n/g' |
  tail -n1 |
  sed 's/.*"title":"\([^"]\+\)".*"artist":"\([^"]\+\)".*"album":"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1*\2*\3/'
```

PS: You can also use `jq` and skip the `php`:

```
curl -s http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory |
  grep -o '\[{"timestamp":.*\]' |
  jq '.[length-1] | .title,.artist,.album' |
  tr '\n' '*'
```

Comment: Wow, your second answer here works perfectly! Did not even think it could be that simple, wish I could mark 2 answers here!

Comment: glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for `curl`, `sed`, `jq`, etc. [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), a HTML/XML/JSON parser (using CSS, XPath, XQuery, JSONiq and pattern templates) can do it all by it self.

Open the url, extract and parse the json starting with `var songs =`:

```sh
xidel -s http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory -e '
  json(
    //script/extract(
      .,
      "var songs = (.+);",
      1
    )[.]
  )
'
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1555445370000,
    "title": "Fortunate Son",
    "trackId": "4a_26b57ded-d5bd-42f8-a440-d8fd5b48c6c2",
    "artist": "Creedence Clearwater Revival",
    "artistId": "1d_44c48a1b-defd-4222-bee6-03f9ee9a7be9",
    "album": "Platinum",
    "albumId": "07_9b0f8fc8-65d8-4321-9699-57ce36e192d0",
    "npe_id": "514295ba2099e4deaca9291d1affa49a43"
  },
  [...]
  {
    "timestamp": 1555448565000,
    "title": "Lunatic Fringe",
    "trackId": "35_725d3938-1ddb-43b7-b6a3-5a8be7a23dee",
    "artist": "Red Rider",
    "artistId": "14_a22d8a5d-1ca1-43cf-85a6-07f64a18273d",
    "album": "As Far As Siam",
    "albumId": "86_e1d05a59-4817-43e9-a315-09e953035b19",
    "npe_id": "8834a1fecc4f06783f155494497a1c7110"
  }
]
```

Return the array's last object:

```sh
xidel -s http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory -e '
  json(
    //script/extract(
      .,
      "var songs = (.+);",
      1
    )[.]
  )()[last()]
'
{
  "timestamp": 1555448565000,
  "title": "Lunatic Fringe",
  "trackId": "35_725d3938-1ddb-43b7-b6a3-5a8be7a23dee",
  "artist": "Red Rider",
  "artistId": "14_a22d8a5d-1ca1-43cf-85a6-07f64a18273d",
  "album": "As Far As Siam",
  "albumId": "86_e1d05a59-4817-43e9-a315-09e953035b19",
  "npe_id": "8834a1fecc4f06783f155494497a1c7110"
}
```

String-join the title, artist and album:

```sh
xidel -s http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory -e '
  json(
    //script/extract(
      .,
      "var songs = (.+);",
      1
    )[.]
  )()[last()]/join(
    (
      title,
      artist,
      album
    ),
    "*"
  )
'
Lunatic Fringe*Red Rider*As Far As Siam
```

One-liner:

```sh
xidel -s http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory -e 'json(//script/extract(.,"var songs = (.+);",1)[.])()[last()]/join((title,artist,album),"*")'
```